# Android's resource "@id" mechanism to assign id in custom XML file

Tags: android, xml, xsd

Is it possible to use the `@id/name` and `@+id/name` mechanism used in Android XML files on my own custom defined XML files?

Inside an Android project I have an XSD schema file and several custom XMLs using that schema.
Some elements have an `id` field, which I would like to assign the same way as I assign ids to android elements; to ensure that across my custom XML files all ids are unique.

**Edit**
The original question was poorly described. Let me clarify:
The `@id` mechanism is usable inside custom XML files, I can write

```
<myelem id="@+id/name"/>
```

the problem is when I try to validate the XML file `@id/name` (or `@+id/name`) is not recognized as `unsignedInt`, which is the type of the id field.

```
cvc-attribute.3: The value '@+id/name' of attribute 'id' on element 'myelem' is not valid with respect to its type, 'unsignedInt'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define IDs in a resources XML file and use that in your XML.

```
<item name="idname" type="id" />
```

And then, when you parse your XML you can compare the value with the one from the [resources](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(idname, "id", context.getPackageName());
```

Comment: It is not really what I need, I phrased my question poorly, I will edit it.

Comment: @ilomambo: What you want is not possible. The answer given here is the best you can do, and assumes that you modify your schemas such that the `id` attributes support strings, which you "patch up" to be integers when parsing.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think I've come up with a solution, and it would be to put a pattern restriction on the id field, in the XSD. Something like `[0-9]+|\@\+?id\/[a-z][a-z0-9]*` and then retrieve the resource id during the element construccion code. I still have to try it.